# SSH not working

Tags: ssh

So I followed this guide: https://bensmann.no/restrict-sftp-users-to-home-folder/
(I did not do the /bin/false command).

After the change in the sshd_config file it does not start anymore. I ran the systemctl status ssh.service comand and the output said that it Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.

Any ideas lads?

Comment: If it was working before you changed the config file, revert the changes and examine what you did.

Comment: Was the computer you were sshing to on? Yes I had that problem.

Comment: Run the ssh server manually and see what errors are causing it to fail.  `/usr/bin/sshd -dd`.

Comment: I bet if you look harder at the logs, it will tell you exactly which line number of `sshd_config` has an issue.

Comment: Hi all! I haven't been able to work futher on the project until now. I commented out the lines I added to the config file and tested to start the ssh aerver manually and it started without problems. This is no surprise though since it worked before I added the new lines. Since my way to restric the user to the home directory did not work, am I wondering if maybe someone knows a good guide to how to restrict a user to the home directory through a ssh connection.